# Excel, if 2 values match across different sheets then list 3rd value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in Excel;

Sheet 1 shows the time and date (column C) a user (column D) logged in  (sometimes multiple logins per day).

Sheet 2 is a list of users (column D) and the team they sit in (Column E).

What I need is a formula on sheet 1 in a new column that basically say if the user in sheet 1, column D, matches the user in sheet 2 column D, pull through the team in from sheet 2, column E.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin!

I've tried vlookup and if statements but neither have worked

Comment: Please share how you have used `VLOOKUP()` since that would be a perfect solution to your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a formula like this?

```
=VLOOKUP(D2;Sheet2!$C$1:$D$4;2;FALSE)
```

I have a Sheet1 with four users (from 1 to 4) and three of them (1, 3 and 4) belong to a team. The formula yields a result like the following:

[image: Excel screenshot Sheet1]

For your information, my Sheet2 looks as follows:

[image: Excel screenshot Sheet2]

Comment: Your example above is exactly right, but every time I try this I get Excel saying "there is a problem with this formula". Every user has a team name assigned in sheet 2, there will be no N/A so I know that's not the issue

Comment: "a problem with this formula", that gives me the impression that you're experiencing locale related issues, like "Are you using the right delimiter in your formula?" (comma or semicolon), "Are the names of your functions correct (`VLookup()` or some local translation, ...)?", things like that. If you don't find it out, please take a screenshot of your formula and put it in your question (you can edit the question for that).

Answer (score 0):

`IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2, Sheet2!D:E, 2, FALSE), "DNE")`

This should work for sheet 1. The IFERROR handles cases where the user does not exist in sheet 2, and the team will be DNE (you can replace it with whatever you want). This should work for row 2, and if you just drag it down to the rest of the rows it should work for all: